# SQL query debug

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can someone explain me this mysql query:

```
SELECT E.*,
 LAST_DAY(
  STR_TO_DATE(
   concat(
     LPAD(
       month(
         STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(C.month, 1, 3),'%b')), 2, 0
     ), '/', '01',  '/', C.year),'%m/%d/%Y')) as calendar_date
```

I don't understand what date it selects.... one week, or?

Comment: Kinda hard to know without the rest of the query, and info about the tables used.

Comment: it returns a `date` (or a datetime) of the last day of the month (like the 28th 29th 30th or 31st, but in a full date format, based on the date that came in via the aliased table c. So it sorta creates a new string interally on the fly making the date the first of the month. But the outer wrapper brings back the last day of the month. So, calendar_date is going to look like `2016-09-30` for instance

Comment: This is not a legal query, it has no FROM clause

Comment: They seemed to have felt the need to reset it back to `mm/01/yyyy` prior to doing `last_day()` which allegedly is not necessary anyway. But maybe it is due to the input and seeing the `%b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the str_to_date's use of `%b` and reading the following:
[MySQL: STR_TO_DATE Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date.php),

the data would have to have date info like JAN FEB MAR which explains the substring of 3 usage. As said in comments, it returns the last date of the month such as

```
2006-01-31
2016-09-30
```

MySQL Manual Page for [`str_to_date()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [`LPAD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

As for LPAD, that one left pads the month with leading left-most 0's. In that case just one, so a 7 would go to `07`, for instance, for July. A `Date` of `2016-7-31` would not be happy later. But a `Date` of `2016-07-31` would be.

Answer (score 0):

Probably,
c.month is 'January', 'February', ...
and c.year is any year (2016, 2017, ...).

The **return** is:
The last day of the c.month in that c.year.

**EDIT**
To make it much better, you could do like it:

```
select last_day(STR_TO_DATE(concat(C.year,', ' C.month), '%Y, %M'));
```